# Need list of unequal lengths to be paired with year

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of five lists, each with a different number of elements

```
   list = {RandomReal[{0, 1}, 7], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 9], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 11], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, 13]}
```

Each of these lists occur in certain unique years (the number of years matching the number of lists)

```
yrs = Range[1990, 1994]
```

I can laboriously make a set of pairs for each year

```
 Transpose[{ConstantArray[1990, Length[list[[1]]]], list[[1]]}]
Transpose[{ConstantArray[1991, Length[list[[2]]]], list[[2]]}]
```

But since my actual data is much larger, it would be easier if it were all done in a single blow.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) with [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html).

With `list` and `yrs` in OP then

```
res = MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {yrs, list}];
```

Then for first year

```
res[[1]]
```

> ```
> {{1990, 0.151543}, {1990, 0.944944}, {1990, 0.538527}, {1990, 0.63919}
>  , {1990, 0.971325}, {1990, 0.636851}, {1990, 0.543734}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried every possible combination of Map and MapThread and Thread EXCEPT using two of them together

Answer (score 3):

```
f1 = Map[Thread] @* Thread;

f1 @ {yrs, list}
```

[image]

Additional variations:

```
f2 = MapThread[Thread @* List];

f3 = Map[Thread] @* Thread @* List;

f1 @ {yrs, list} == f2 @ {yrs, list} == f3[yrs, list]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[42];
list = {RandomReal[{0, 1}, 7], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 9], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 11], 
  RandomReal[{0, 1}, 13]}
yrs = Range[1990, 1994]

t1 = Inner[Thread[{##}] &, yrs, list, List]
```

---

a variation of the answer by @kglr (without compositions):

```
t2 = Thread /@ Thread[{yrs, list}]
```

---

```
t3 = Thread /@ Transpose[{yrs, list}]
```

---

result:

```
> {{{1990, 0.425905}, {1990, 0.391023}, {1990, 0.347069}, {1990, 
>    0.453741}, {1990, 0.555963}, {1990, 0.289169}, {1990, 
>    0.296848}}, {{1991, 0.206408}, {1991, 0.32517}, {1991, 
>    0.973325}, {1991, 0.258796}, {1991, 0.550582}, {1991, 
>    0.717287}, {1991, 0.754353}, {1991, 0.860349}, {1991, 
>    0.996966}}, {{1992, 0.739226}, {1992, 0.0383646}, {1992, 
>    0.376127}, {1992, 0.296199}, {1992, 0.528142}}, {{1993, 
>    0.607352}, {1993, 0.902795}, {1993, 0.840683}, {1993, 
>    0.885752}, {1993, 0.527083}, {1993, 0.560605}, {1993, 
>    0.924421}, {1993, 0.00157704}, {1993, 0.90062}, {1993, 
>    0.367489}, {1993, 0.274115}}, {{1994, 0.97712}, {1994, 
>    0.96073}, {1994, 0.478762}, {1994, 0.848851}, {1994, 
>    0.352932}, {1994, 0.799515}, {1994, 0.365826}, {1994, 
>    0.739896}, {1994, 0.789536}, {1994, 0.807022}, {1994, 
>    0.534674}, {1994, 0.164278}, {1994, 0.362973}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is the obvious generalization

```
f[m_] := 
 Transpose[{ConstantArray[yrs[[m]], Length[list[[m]]]], list[[m]]}]
```

Compare to what you did manually

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[
 f[1] - Transpose[{ConstantArray[1990, Length[list[[1]]]], 
    list[[1]]}]]

LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[
 f[2] - Transpose[{ConstantArray[1991, Length[list[[2]]]], 
    list[[2]]}]]
```

both of which give you

> [image: true]

which means that the automated and manual results are equivalent.

Create a list with everything together can be done effortlessly

```
ff = Table[
   Transpose[{ConstantArray[yrs[[m]], Length[list[[m]]]], 
     list[[m]]}], {m, 1, Length@yrs}];
```

And now

```
ff[[1]]
```

gives exactly `res[[1]]` - see the accepted solution. Equivalently `f[1]` is also the same with `res[[1]]`